# Magento 2 What are the Custom Attributes Node when Creating a new Product Type?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, refund, product-type

I've had a look at how to create new product types in magento. Looking through the core code I found the following:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="simple" label="Simple Product" modelInstance="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple" indexPriority="10" sortOrder="10">
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
</config>
```

What exactly does the `customAttributes` do? And Where is the `refundable` attribute store?

**EDIT:** 
I've had a look at the attributes both in the database and admin panel, I can't find a reference to the `refundable` attribute. One of my colleagues told me its probably some kind of "virtual attribute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What exactly does the `customAttributes` do?

We should take a look: [\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\Config::filter()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductTypes/Config.php#L81)
The `customAttributes` nodes can be used when Magento wants to get list of product types that comply with condition.
Inside this node, we can declare some attributes nodes:

- `refundable` will check the product type: it can be refunded or not. By default Magento CE, the downloadable and virtual product cannot be refunded (Magento EE added Gift  product). **If working with EE version, we can see this attribute will be used in RMA module**. The product type in sales order item table will be used for checking the refundable product.
- `is_real_product` is used for checking "it is a real product or not". Not real products: Group product, Downloadable Product, Virtual Product.
- `is_product_set` checks whether product type is set of products: [\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\Config::isProductSet()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductTypes/Config.php#L59)